# How to revert back to ALSA?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, alsa, elementary-os, oss

I wanted to try out `oss` because sound on `alsa` is not great. I am on `elementaryOS Loki` which is built on `ubuntu`.

Anyways I installed `alsa-oss` using `sudo apt-get install alsa-oss` but it didn't recognize my sound card(its `Realtek ac290`). So I uninstalled it and now I dont have any sound. I have tried reinstalling `alsa` using

```
 sudo aptitude --purge reinstall linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils linux-image-`uname -r` linux-ubuntu-modules-`uname -r` libasound2
```

but this doesnt fix anything, still no sound.
When I type `alsamixer` in terminal I get
:`cannot open mixer: No such file or directory`

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)
```

This command reinstalled all the missing drivers and fixed the problem.
I will just leave it here so that it can help others in future.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/940091/ubuntu-16-04-reinstall-all-drivers